# Direct Form I Filter from Direct Form II

Tags: filters, c

I am looking a way to make outputs match. For len 160 wouldnt the error be significant? For 40 ?  I have included some sample output showing the error.
 **Direct Form 2 Original**

```
void highpass(const short int *x, short int *y, int len, int filtID, long int *mem)
{
    int i;

    const short int Pcoef[5][3] = { { 16384, -31313, 14991 }, { 16384, -31569, 15249 }, { 16384, -31677, 15328 }, { 16384, -32313, 15947 }, { 16384, -22446, 6537 } };
    const short int Zcoef[5][3] = { { 15672, -31344, 15672 }, { 15802, -31601, 15802 }, { 15847, -31694, 15847 }, { 16162, -32322, 16162 }, { 14418, -28836, 14418 } };

    int j;
    const short int *den, *num;
    if (filtID > 4)
        filtID = 4;

    den = Pcoef[filtID]; num = Zcoef[filtID];
    /*return;*/
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        short int yi;

        long int vout = ADD32(MULT16_16(num[0], x[i]), mem[0]);
        yi = EXTRACT16(SATURATE(PSHR32(vout, 14), 32767));
        mem[0] = ADD32(MAC16_16(mem[1], num[1], x[i]),
            SHL32(MULT16_32_Q15(-den[1], vout), 1));
        mem[1] = ADD32(MULT16_16(num[2], x[i]), SHL32(MULT16_32_Q15(-den[2], vout), 1));
        y[i] = yi;

    }
}
```

**Direct Form 1**

```
 void highpass24DF1(const short int *x, short int *y, int len, int filtID, long int *mem)
        {
            int i;

            const short int Pcoef[5][3] = { { 16384, -31313, 14991 }, { 16384, -31569, 15249 }, { 16384, -31677, 15328 }, { 16384, -32313, 15947 }, { 16384, -22446, 6537 } };
            const short int Zcoef[5][3] = { { 15672, -31344, 15672 }, { 15802, -31601, 15802 }, { 15847, -31694, 15847 }, { 16162, -32322, 16162 }, { 14418, -28836, 14418 } };

            int j;
            const short int *den, *num;
            if (filtID > 4)
                filtID = 4;

            den = Pcoef[filtID]; num = Zcoef[filtID];

            long yi1 = 0;
            long yi2 = 0;
            long yi = 0;

            long mx1 = 0;
            long mx2 = 0;


            for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {

                yi

     += num[0] * x[i] + num[1] * mx1 + num[2] * mx2;
            yi -= den[1] * yi1 + den[2] * yi2;

            yi = PSHR32(yi, 14);

            y[i] = EXTRACT16(SATURATE(yi, 32767));

            yi2 = yi1;
            yi1 = yi;
            mx2 = mx1;
            mx1 = x[i];
            yi = 0;
        }
    }
```

**Input**

```
short int entrada[10] = { 32494, 32494, 32494, -32494, -32494, 32494, 32494, -32494, 32494, 32494 };
```

[image]

Comment: there are a lotta #undefined MACROs or functions like EXTRACT16, etc.  anyway, you can spell out in simple C what your DF2 is doing and it's not hard to switch around a few statements and make it a DF1.

Comment: I have implemented both as you see but output doesnt match. https://github.com/okamstudio/godot/blob/master/drivers/speex/fixed_generic.h  here are the macros